# How to change google chart title font size?

Tags: html, google-visualization

How do I change the font size of my title in google chart?

```
   var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      'backgroundColor': 'transparent',   
      is3D: true,
    };
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use titleTextStyle in options like this

```js
var options = {
    titleTextStyle: {
        color: <string>,    // any HTML string color ('red', '#cc00cc')
        fontName: <string>, // i.e. 'Times New Roman'
        fontSize: <number>, // 12, 18 whatever you want (don't specify px)
        bold: <boolean>,    // true or false
        italic: <boolean>   // true of false
    }
}
```

You can find a complete support guide for Google Charts here
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs

Comment: can we make it responsive ?? means in google chrome its works fine but in mozilla fontsize not set as per screen size

Comment: For calendar chart see https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar and do a search on the page (CTRL + F) with `fontsize` you'll find what you need

Comment: @j3ff How about [multiple font sizes for a multi-line chart title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58869523/how-would-i-be-able-display-the-title-in-two-lines).

Comment: How can we add the background color around the text?

Comment: try auraColor from https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart#customizing-labels