# Adding an HTML rendered title in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to create an HTML rendered title in Google Charts. I want to create a string variable that contains HTML code and then pass it on as the title of the chart. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfuohxcp/). Here's what I'm trying to do:

**HTML**

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

**JS**

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
  });
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);



  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work', 11],
      ['Eat', 2],
      ['Commute', 2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep', 7]
    ]);

    var ch = "<span>Hello World!</span>";

    ch = $($.parseHTML(ch));

    var options = {
      title: ch
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

When I try outputting the string as a title, I get [object object]. I tried doing `$($.parseHTML(ch)).html();` but it looks like this strips the HTML tags because when I add styling to the span element it doesn't style the title. What should I do to get an HTML string to be displayed as a title with styling?

Comment: @WhiteHat How do I change the SVG manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `titleTextStyle` option applies to the entire chart title,
it is not possible using standard config options to style only part of the title

it will also not accept html, since it is drawn using svg

you could use an adjacent `<div>` and leave the title out of the options,
or change the title's svg once the chart's `'ready'` event fires...

the title will be in a svg `<text>` element,
to separate the title from the other `<text>` elements on the chart,
use an initial value that can be used to find it...

```
var options = {
  title: 'chartTitle'
};
```

in the ready handler, find the element...

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
  var chartTitle = $('#chart text').filter(':contains("chartTitle")')[0];
});
```

use the `<tspan>` element to style different parts of the `<text>` element
result may look something like this...

```
<text><tspan style="font-weight: bold;">Chart</tspan> Title</text>
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {label: 'x', type: 'string'},
        {label: 'y0', type: 'number'},
      ],
      rows: [
        {c:[{v: 'row 0'}, {v: 10}]},
        {c:[{v: 'row 1'}, {v: 5}]},
        {c:[{v: 'row 2'}, {v: 1}]},
        {c:[{v: 'row 3'}, {v: 2}]},
        {c:[{v: 'row 4'}, {v: 8}]}
      ]
    });

    var options = {
      title: 'chartTitle'
    };

    var container = document.getElementById('chart');
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      var svgNS = $('#chart svg')[0].namespaceURI;
      var chartTitle = $('#chart text').filter(':contains("chartTitle")')[0];
      $(chartTitle).text('');

      var textStyle = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'tspan');
      $(textStyle).attr('fill', '#ff0000');
      $(textStyle).attr('font-weight', 'bold');
      $(textStyle).text('Chart ');
      $(chartTitle).append(textStyle);

      var textStyle = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'tspan');
      $(textStyle).attr('fill', '#0000ff');
      $(textStyle).attr('font-weight', 'normal');
      $(textStyle).text('Title');
      $(chartTitle).append(textStyle);
    });
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about editing it with HTML/CSS but you can use something that google-charts offers with `titleTextStyle`

```
var options = {
titleTextStyle: {
    color: <string>,    // any HTML string color ('red', '#cc00cc')
    fontName: <string>, // i.e. 'Times New Roman'
    fontSize: <number>, // 12, 18 whatever you want (don't specify px)
    bold: <boolean>,    // true or false
    italic: <boolean>   // true of false
}
}
```

Comes from this stack answer: [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176219/how-to-change-google-chart-title-font-size)

Google Documentation here: [Chart Customization](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_charts)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to stylize different parts of the title. So for example, I want part of the title bold and the other normal