# Google Charts multiple colors in axis title

Tags: charts, colors, google-visualization

Is there any way to set multiple colors in an axis title in google charts? Through the charts options or jQuery?

For instance, I have this graph:
[image]

I set the Orange Y-axis title to orange with `{title:'Orange', minValue: 0, titleTextStyle:{color: 'orange'}}`. I would like to set the other Y-axis title so that green is the color green and blue is the color blue. Seems simple but is it possible?

Comment: multiple colors are not available via standard config options, you will need to manually change when the chart's `'ready'` event fires -- you replace the contents of the `<text>` elements with multiple `<tspan>` elements -- here are a couple examples, [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765057/5090771) & [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45573868/5090771)

Comment: @WhiteHat Cool thanks, that's all I really wanted to know. If you want to submit this as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can just fix it like this:

```
 hAxis: {title: 'Date de Prélévement',titleTextStyle:{color: '#FFF'}, textStyle: {color: '#FFF'  , fontSize: 10} },
          vAxis: {title: 'Heures de sommeil',titleTextStyle:{color: '#FFF'},  textStyle: {color: '#FFF'  , fontSize: 10} },
```