# Google Charts title font-size css flexible attribute?

Tags: google-visualization

I'm working with Google Charts Combo Charts. According to  [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart) I can only specify `titleTextStyle` `fontSize` in pixels (px).

Instead, I want to control `fontSize` with css-like flexible attributes, e.g. (`%` or `vw`). The built-in options are not sufficient for a chart that needs to scale up to 4k (3840+px) and scale down to mobile (320-415px).

```
var options = {
    titleTextStyle: {
        fontName: <string>, // i.e. 'Times New Roman'
        fontSize: <number>, // e.g. 12 (px is implied)
    }
}
```

I have seen that it is possible to map css formatting to Google Charts Table Chart by using the [cssClassNames option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table) but I can't find any documentation for cssClassNames with Combo Chart. Search attempts have come up empty.

Someone else has also asked
[How to change google chart title font size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176219/how-to-change-google-chart-title-font-size)

Comment: in order to make a google chart responsive, it needs to be re-drawn after the screen size changes. in the following example, you can see the font size of the chart title changes when the screen is re-sized. run the snippet in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56443537/5090771), then click the "Full page" link at the top right of the snippet. in this example, no font size option has been provided. you just need to make sure there is enough room at the top for the title to actually be responsive, see the `chartArea` config option.

Comment: or you could manually set the font size option based on screen size and re-draw the chart.